# Keep one maximum values from multiple maximum values in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have a matrix that defines the cluster assignments for multiple documents to cluster centroids, this matrix has rows as the documents and columns as the cluster centroids, what I want to do is that keep just one cluster assignment and remove the rest basically break cluster ties for the documents. Here is an example:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0    0    1
[2,]  1    1    0
[3,]  1    0    0
```

So document 2 is assigned to cluster 1 and also to cluster 2, what I want is just to keep one cluster assignment, for now I am trying to keep the cluster assignment which has the lowest index, so document 2 should be assigned to cluster 1. I am stuck as to how can implement this in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `which.max` and `which.is.max` (the latter is in the `nnet` package) already solve your problem. `which.max` returns the first maximum, and `which.is.max` breaks ties at random.

```
apply(m, 1, which.max)
```

or

```
apply(m, 1, which.is.max)
```

Comment: Also `max.col`, `max.col(m, "first")`.

Comment: How do I convert my matrix into one where there are only one 1's per row using this function, I tried many approaches but each time it returns me a vector of positions that contain the first maximum element, please can you provide me a code snippet.